# Spark job with no input dataset

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing

I want to write a Spark job that produces millions of random numbers as output. This does not need an input dataset, but it would be good to have the parallelism of a cluster.

I understand that Spark runs on RDD which are datasets by definition, I am just wondering if there is a way to force many executors to run a specific function without having an RDD, or by creating a mock RDD.

Comment: Ofc, you can generate random data RDDs with Spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(1000, 1000, 1000))
.repartition(3)
.flatMap({count => 0.to(count).map(_ => Random.nextInt)})
```

Comment: You can do more than just basic sequence flat maps. I'm just not on my of to write an answer :)